# Bitmap heap scan on new partitioned tables

Tags: postgresql

I'm using table partitioning to store messages partitioned by month. This month our website went down because querying the new month performed very bad. Still no clue why.

Explain for a query on the previous month (~200M rows)

https://explain.depesz.com/s/yGDH

Explain for the same query on the current month (~400k rows)

https://explain.depesz.com/s/g7fV

As you can see in the explains, one is using an index scan (conv_id, with filter on 'created') and the other is first doing a bitmap heap scan following an bitmap index scan.

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE conv_messages
(
    conv_message_id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    conv_id bigint NOT NULL,
    message text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    message_type smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    unread boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    from_user_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT convmessages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (conv_message_id, created)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created) ;


CREATE INDEX conv_messages_unreads
    ON conv_messages USING btree
    (unread ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default
    WHERE unread IS TRUE;

CREATE INDEX ix_convm_user_id
    ON conv_messages USING btree
    (from_user_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX ix_convmessages_convid
    ON conv_messages USING btree
    (conv_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX ix_convmessages_created
    ON conv_messages USING btree
    (created DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

and the (simple) query:

```
select * from conv_messages m
    where
     m.created >= '2020-03-01 00:00:00' and
     m.created < '2020-04-01 00:00:00' and
     m.conv_id = 259395024
    order by m.created desc
    limit 20  offset 0;
```

I don't understand why a the partitioned table with 200m+ rows performs 40x faster than the one with only 400k rows in it, considering the tables are the same. I tried reindexing the created_ix and conv_id_ix but that didn't make any difference.

Anyone knows what could be going on here? I'm using postgresql 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the bad mis-estimate. Try increasing `default_statistics_target`, see that autoanalyze runs often on the table; that may make the difference.

Comment: Thanks! After reading the docs I decided to increase it a bit and the query times went to 0.2ms! Not bad.